# Load HBase records from PIG conditionally

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hive, apache-pig

Is there a way to load records from HBase into a pig relation based on the value of a particular column in HBase? Thank You

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the [source code for the pig HBase loader](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.java?view=markup) you can see  it can filter on key range and timestamps and it can get columns by prefix but not filter by column value.

You can write your own loader (even based on that code) and add the capability you need. Note that the performance for filtering on column values would not be great anyway and filtering for that value in the mapper, while slower than filtering in an HBase filter, will not be that different (you'd be basically saving the interprocess communication from the regionserver to the pig mapper)

Comment: it depends on what version of pig/hbase you are using whether timestamp filtering is available. this was introduced in pig 0.10.0. if you are using cloudera, though, it's harder to tell what release this came out in, but it's definitely after 0.10.0-cdh4.1.3 (unfortunately for me, since that is the release my company is stuck at). your best way to tell what flags you can filter with is to get the source code for your version of pig and look at the HBaseStorage class.